# Facebook SDK for Unity on Android - Trouble about callback from FB.Login

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I'm having some problem about login in facebook-unity-sdk on android device. When I login and get callback, them return this

FBResult.Text

```
{"is_logged_in":false,"user_id":"","access_token":""}
```

FBResult.Error

```
null
```

and FB.IsLoggedIn is null everytime after login completed

I'm using last version of Facebook SDK (4.2.1) and Unity 4.2

On Debug Log

```
Send to Unity OnLoginCompleted({"cancelled":true})
```

Comment: we're still testing this, but if you'd like to try the latest sdk, here is a link to it: http://unite-friend-smash.parseapp.com/v4.2.4/FacebookSDK.unitypackage thanks for trying the SDK!

Comment: **Note for 2014 -- this problem is the 'it works if the user does NOT have the fb app installed' problem.  Note that >>> SOMETIMES <<< the solution is very simple; you have forgotten to put the right values on the developers.facebook site.**  Brian from FB kindly explains here (note his images) http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/543540/facebook-sdk-v424-android-login-not-working.html  Hope this helps someone, it's a real shitty problem if you get caught in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem has resolved now. This problem is about Multi-Plugin on project. Now (I think), Facebook SDK can't use with other plugin that want main activity for them on android. Export android project and recheck AndroidManifest.xml and maintain them for right things, It should have FBUnityActivity for singletask that many plugin override them so facebook can't get session on game launch. Hope for next version this SDK can use with another plugin. Thank you everyone for advise :)

Answer (score 2):

These problems are usually caused by two things:

#### Keyhash setup

You can set your logcat to filter messages with log tag "fb4a" and you will see underlying Facebook Android SDK throwing exception saying your keyhash doesn't match any stored keyhashes.

You can just copy that keyhash and add it to Facebook developer dashboard.

#### Other plugins

We have new v5.0.2 beta version of the SDK which should play nice with other plugins.

Check Brian's answer in this thread [How to work with Facebook SDK for Unity and Vuforia for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20928723/how-to-work-with-facebook-sdk-for-unity-and-vuforia-for-android)

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of the sdk fixes this and is available for download here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/downloads/

Comment: Thank you benp, But I still has this problem in V4.2.4, How to solve in this version?

Comment: Could you send us your project to debug? Try unity-sdk@fb.com if you'd just like to mail it to us. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I use example scene from packages and It show me on debugging log.

Comment: Recently, I try android SDK tutorial and It can run clearly! but for Unity SDK, It still has problem.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved by try download new openssl from this

http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/openssl.htm

and change new hash key.

Answer (score 0):

have the same problem, I export the test scene as is and does not work with facebook app installed.

Im using sdk v4.2.4.

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading your openSSL and regenerating the keyhash, I was stuck on this issue for a few days trying over and over again everything that came to my mind... Until I read someone did that so I tried and magic ! All the test projects I tried to make the FB SDK work with are doing just fine ;)

I used the one from [this page](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/openssl.htm) if anyone wonders.

Such a waste of time that would have been avoided if the error field did tell what was wrong...

Comment: Thank you @met44 for suggestion, I try update openssl, rm debug.keystore and get new one but it still has problem. I hope its will fix on next versions soon.

Comment: Do you see a valid heyhash in the Facebook settings within Unity ? And did you sign your app with your debug keystore ?

Comment: Yes, I do. My keyhash's valid within Unity and result from debug.keystore but I don't know what's my fault.

Comment: One of the best way to check your settings is to create a brand new project and import the facebook sdk, from there, go through the Facebook setting process of app id, class names, as well as keystore etc and set the demo scene as the startup scene. 

Then run this project on your device, this is the simplest form a facebook project can take and it does work once everything is setup properly so until you get this to work you may consider something isn't setup how it should...

Answer (score 0):

What about release keystore, I am signing my app with Unity , and I get the keyhash from the keystore that Unity created, but same error, login shows up , but is_logged_in :false

Answer (score 0):

The Facebook Unity plugin for Android doesn't play nice with other plugins as it
overrides the MainActivity, so unless you launch it first (from the AndroidManifest.xml)
it won't return any data (login info, friend lists) back to Unity and to your game.

Of course, most other plugins now don't work.

I have my own plugin (pure java compiled in eclipse) that handles Saving, IAP, notifications, etc and i launch that plugin first - to make the Facebook plugin work you have to add a small bit of Facebook "Session" code to onActivityResult in your own Main Activity class:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    // Pass on the activity result to the helper for handling
    if (!mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
        // not handled, so handle it ourselves (here's where you'd
        // perform any handling of activity results not related to in-app
        // billing...

        // Facebook callback

        if (Session.getActiveSession() != null) {
            Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode,
                    resultCode, data);
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    } else {
    }
}
```

You need the FacebookSDK.jar for this to compile, and i was as surprised as anyone
when it worked; but this won't help if you are using other 3rd party plugins and
don't have access to their source.

Writing Unity plugins for Android is a nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

@user2830062 re-checking your keyhash. When you was get correct keyhash, with each computer you need get new keyhash and add to dev facebook page (list keyhash)