# Facebook Login don't work on Win, but works on MacOS

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

When I run test projects on Android device, I see strange thing: 
Build on Win7 doesn't work (login return aborted:"true"), but exactly the same project, what builded on MacOS works perfect.
I guess problem in key hashes generation (but in Facebook App Settings both of it (Win, MacOS) added).

Comment: Can you provide the code that you use for facebook login? Do you use a Unity plugin to achievet his, or written everything yourself?

Comment: Can you show the code, then it will be easy for us to help you

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19051361/facebook-unity-sdk-on-android-login-fails-when-fb-app-installed
Certain versions of openssl can give back the wrong key hash.  It seems like you may be running up against the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your problem is probably related to keyhash configuration.

To make sure, you can set your logcat to filter messages with log tag "fb4a" and you will see underlying Facebook Android SDK throwing exception saying your keyhash doesn't match any stored keyhashes.

You can just copy that keyhash and add it to Facebook developer dashboard.