# Facebook Login is not working When App is already installed : Unity3d

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I have dowloaded friend smash game from facebook and then imported latest Facebook SDK 5.0.3..

Now Login is not working when facebook app is already installed in any android device.

So what can be the problem?

And i have signed apk and generated HashKey for that signed apk. So it does not have any issue with hashkey.. even i have checked in log..

```
void LoginCallback(FBResult result)
    {
        FbDebug.Log("LoginCallback");
        Debug.Log("Error :" + result.Text); 
        if (FB.IsLoggedIn)
        {
            OnLoggedIn();
            FB.API ( 
                    "/me?fields=id,first_name,picture,friends.limit(100).fields(first_name,id)", 
                    Facebook.HttpMethod.GET, 
                    APICallback 
                    ); 
        }
    }
```

For this log message is coming like this :

```
03-15 12:35:46.208: I/Unity(5581): Error :{"is_logged_in":false,"user_id":"","access_token":"","access_token_expires_at":"01/01/0001 00:00:00"}
```

I dont find any solution for this. Please help me guys..

Thanks for your support and help till now..

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem like your said.It work well in IOS,but cann't working when the facebook app is already in the android device.I wish someone can help solve this.

Comment: These questions are related .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19051361/facebook-unity-sdk-on-android-login-fails-when-fb-app-installed

Comment: I had solved it,because my openssl setting is wrong.It must be openssl base64.If not,keyHash is wrong,when facebook app is already in android device,it can't find the our app.It make facebook sdk can't work.

Comment: Good one, GS.  For anyone googling here, if you are having this notorious problem on Unity3D/Mac, the only solution is here: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/609810/using-facebook-api-with-android-says-login-is-canc.html  Hope it helps.